# How to integrate trading view charting library in my website

Tags: javascript, json, tradingview-api

Iam  building a website for bitcoin exchange. I want to use trading view [charting library](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library) I extracted it in my workspace. I want to know how to give my own datafeed. Which format should datafeed file be in (like php,js,json) ?

```
var _datafeed = new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("http://localhost/workspace/charting");
    //var _datafeed = new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("https://demo_feed.tradingview.com");

    TradingView.onready(function () {
        var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
            debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
            fullscreen: false,
            symbol: 'A',
            interval: 'D',
            timezone: "America/New_York",
            container_id: "tv_chart_container",
            locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
            datafeed: _datafeed,
            library_path: "charting_library/",
        });
    });
```

In above code the charts are plotted with demo link. when I change it to my path, I get 'invalid symbol' error. Where do I specify config and symbol_info and what's their file format? Iam a total newbie. Please help .

Any suggestion to move in the right way is appreciated. I am STUCK!!

[Screen shot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7inyN.png)

Comment: Please tell me how to improve my question when you downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a php file and .htaccess in a folder within charting library. htaccess should rewrite all requests to that folder to that php file. Then in that php file echo results in UDF format.

[UDF format and required api calls with sample result](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/UDF)

UPDATE: Trading view charting library is a private repository. so you need to agree to their terms to get access the library and wiki pages on github.

Comment: then link that you have given, doesn't help me anymore, becuase I could not understand that, could you please give me any code leve examples to apply that. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure we have to register to access the instruction on using the charts ?

Comment: @Afsanefda I had to register to access the library files from Github. Its always better to register to ask for help/ raise bugs on GitHub also.

Comment: Unfortunately I live in their restrictions area (Iran)  I asked for the repo invitation but they refused to grant me the access. Do you have the repo ? @SMJ

Answer (score 1):

According with this page https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ you do not need add any libraries, just to add the following references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
```

Two nested divs:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="top:0px; left: 0px; height:50%; width:50%;">
   <div id="tradingview_99b08"></div>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->


And set it with a script like this:

  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "exchange",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "0",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_99b08"
}
  );
  </script>
```

Comment: The [TradingView Widget is different from the Charting Library](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#other-questions) (link requires GitHub repo membership). The widget comes with data from TradingView but doesn't have (documented) methods. The OP is asking about Charting Library, which requires supplying a data feed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for node API, it is working well:

https://github.com/bergusman/tradingview-udf-binance-node

For front end you need tradingview's git repository access.